# Generate a unique number that is formed from 2 numbers and vice versa?

Tags: c#

I am not sure if this is possible but,

I have 2 numbers, a 32-bit int x and a 64-bit long y.

Given that 'y' is ALWAYS unique.

Given these numbers, I want to generate a unique identifier which is a 32-bit int.
I should also be able to construct the individual numbers back from the unique identifier.
Is this possible? I apologize if this is the wrong forum to ask, but this is related to C# programming on a project i am working on.

Basically, 'x' refers to a categoryID and 'y' refers to a unique 'categoryItemId' in my database, a single category can have a million of catalogItems.

Thanks!

Comment: So you have a unique 64bit key, and you want to turn that into a unique 32bit key? You're bound to get colisions, according to the [Pigeonhole principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle)

Comment: Do you know what the range would be for your unique 64-bit long 'y'? If they are going to be above Int32.MaxValue (2,147,483,647) or/and below Int32.MinValue (-2,147,483,647) you're going to find this tricky to say the least.

Comment: What is this for? Is this to create a unique id in another table or something like that?

Comment: @theOne : define unique (in this context).

Comment: "a single category can have a million of catalogItems." at most? So If you have no more than say 214 categories, you could do `(int)((categoryID *10000000) + categoryItemId)`. If you can be sure to always have less than a million, you could handle up to 2147 categories. If you either have more categories or more items per category, see Wai Ha Lees answer.

Comment: hi @sr28 yes, it is to create a unique id in another....

Comment: Is it SQL Server? If so this isn't a good way to manage relationships between tables. You should create a unique id automatically as part of adding an entry into the new table and then use Foreign Keys to define your relationship with your other tables.

Answer (score 6):

To sum up:

- You have **96** (== **32** + **64**) bits of possible inputs.
- You want a unique **32** bit value regardless of the input values.
- **32** < **96**

It's not possible. The [entropy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_%28information_theory%29) of your inputs is larger than the entropy of the output.

Comment: Only fractions of those ranges are used. And when Y is unique, you can simply drop X. When the number of Categories is <= 1000 the required space is 10+20, 2 bits to spare.